# read.table and skype first line of a file in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a file such as :

file1.txt

```
#some info
#some other info 
#information again 
# Busco id  Status  Contig  Start   End Score   Length
EOG091B0006 Complete    scaffold_A  9626    40090   11575.7 6724
EOG091B0007 Fragmented  scaffold_B  455 4244    1660.7  935
EOG091B000H Complete    scaffold_C  4456    43328   7631.6  5014
```

and I would like to read such as :

```
Busco id    Status  Contig  Start   End Score   Length
EOG091B0006 Complete    scaffold_A  9626    40090   11575.7 6724
EOG091B0007 Fragmented  scaffold_B    455   4244    1660.7  935
EOG091B000H Complete    scaffold_C  4456    43328   7631.6  5014
```

I tried : 
`tab_busco=read.table(file1.txt",header=T,sep='\t',skip = 4)` but it does not work...

Comment: You closed the bracket earlier. `tab_busco=read.table(file1.txt",header=T,sep='\t',skip = 4)`

Comment: Yes it was just a mistake but it does not work neither. I get ```Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 6 did not have 7 elements```

Comment: Does this work ? `read.table("file1.txt", header = TRUE, skip = 3, comment.char = "@", fill = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the issue is with lines starting with `"#"` because `"#"` is interpreted as comment.

Try replacing it with any other character, for example :

```
df <- read.table("file1.txt", header = TRUE, skip = 3, 
                 comment.char = "@", fill = TRUE)
```